# Does the Linksys Secure Easy Setup (SES) button work with Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, authentication

Does the Linksys [Secure Easy Setup (SES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecureEasySetup) button work with Ubuntu? I'm housesitting for someone tonight, and when I asked what their wireless password was, they told me about the SES button they press on the router.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are asking about is called Wifi Protected Setup (WPS). I found this bug report on Launchpad

[Intergrate Wifi Protected Setup in Network Manager](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/nm-wifi-protected-setup)

I also can give this link

[Sourceforge link to wpsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wpsd/)

regards.

Comment: Are you sure that SES follows the WPS specification?